# how to get the max average sal using mysql?

Tags: mysql

how to get the `max average sal` in an `employee table`;

I have the

> job, deptno,and sal.

I have used this for query:

```
select max(avg(sal))
from emp
group by job;
```

but its not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating your table as:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM emp;
+------+--------+-------+
| job  | deptno | sal   |
+------+--------+-------+
| SSD  |      1 | 58000 |
| SD   |      1 | 20000 |
| GD   |      1 | 35000 |
| AO   |      2 | 40000 |
| AhO  |      2 | 25000 |
| AhO  |      2 | 55000 |
| SSD  |      1 | 68000 |
+------+--------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I run your query, so I got:

```
mysql> select max(avg(sal)) from emp group by job;
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

That is because you have nested two aggregate functions.

To solve your problem, I have changed your query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    job, 
    AVG(sal) AS average_salary
FROM emp 
GROUP BY job
ORDER BY average_salary DESC
LIMIT 1;

+------+----------------+
| job  | average_salary |
+------+----------------+
| SSD  |     63000.0000 |
+------+----------------+
```

Comment: thank you for response. I'm just wondering if its the maximum average salary that will come out not the average salary. I hope it get it right, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the max() function on avg(). Try bringing in the avg() of all the employees grouped by their jobs.

```
 SELECT Avg(sal) AS avg_sal
     FROM   emp
     GROUP  BY job;
```

Then apply max() function on the sub-query.

```
 SELECT Max(avg_sal)
    FROM   (SELECT Avg(sal) AS avg_sal
    FROM   emp
    GROUP  BY job) AS sub_tab;
```